# How to create a function in MySql in window 10 which return single decimal value

Tags: mysql

```
    DELIMITER $$

    CREATE FUNCTION sqypayroll.fn_GetPresentDays(
        EmployeeID int(11),
        MonthID int(11),
        YearID int(11)
    ) 
    RETURNS decimal(25,5)
    DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
          DECLARE PresentDays decimal(25,5);
          select (presents+weekoff+holidays+(halfdayabsent/2)) into PresentDays
          from sqypayroll.month_attendance
          where employeeId=EmployeeID
          and month=MonthID
          and year=YearID limit 0,1;

        return PresentDays;

    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

this is my function but it return wrong value its return 29.00000
but its actual value is 31.00000

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Also ideally `DETERMINISTIC` should be `NOT DETERMINISTIC` or `READS SQL DATA` in the `CREATE FUNCTION` syntax..   *"A routine is considered “deterministic” if it always produces the same result for the same input parameters, and “not deterministic” otherwise. If neither DETERMINISTIC nor NOT DETERMINISTIC is given in the routine definition, the default is NOT DETERMINISTIC. To declare that a function is deterministic, you must specify DETERMINISTIC explicitly. "*

Comment: ...  *"READS SQL DATA indicates that the routine contains statements that read data (for example, SELECT), but not statements that write data. "*   from the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html)